# MYSQL data insert query doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, mysql, insert

This is my insert query.

```
rule_result = max(item_counts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

# DB connection
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="chat_app",use_unicode=True,charset="utf8")
x = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''INSERT into rule_based_results (emotion) values (%s)''',(rule_result))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

There isn't any error. But this query doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my query.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Data not insert to the Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized `x` to your connection's `cursor` object but never used it.

```
x.execute('''INSERT into rule_based_results (emotion) values (%s)''',(rule_result))
conn.commit()
x.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you I made my mistake.